# Mapping Serie and Dataframe values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a Dataframe `df` which columns are `['col_A' , 'col_B', 'col_C']` and it has 1000 rows.

I have also a series that has as index the names of the columns of the DataFrame and a value that is between 0 and 1000.
For instance: s is the Serie as such:

```
Col_A      20
Col_B      0
Col_C      300
```

I would like to change the dataframe as:

```
df.iloc[0:20,0] = a certain value  (column A)
```

I've tried slicing using a for loop but its taking too much time.
is there a pandas function able to do this ?

My code is:

```
for i in range(0,3):
    df.iloc[0:s.iloc[i]-1,i] = -1
```

In a general scope, I sometimes need to map a Series index to a Dataframe column but struggle to find a fast and less consuming method.

Thank you

Comment: Post your code with the loop? An MCVE would be nice.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the code

Comment: Again, mcve would be nice. Not clear where's that `s` coming from.

Comment: @Divakar I've edited, here df is the dataframe and s is the Serie that has as index the name of the columns of df

Comment: You are just looping through 3 cols. That's not a lot. Hence, I am not sure if avoiding the loop would make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Loop**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, (1000,3)), 
                  columns=['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C'])

s = pd.Series([20,0,300], 
              index=['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C'])

for col, idx in s.iteritems():
    df.loc[:idx, col] = -1

df
     col_A  col_B  col_C
0     -999   -999   -999
1     -999      3   -999
2     -999      3   -999
3     -999      2   -999
4     -999      1   -999
..     ...    ...    ...
995      2      6      9
996      1      9      5
997      2      6      4
998      4      0      1
999      9      2      8
```

**Pandas Apply**

```py
def f(c, s):
    c[:s[c.name]] = -1
    return c

df = df.apply(lambda c: f(c,s))
df 
     col_A  col_B  col_C
0       -1      6     -1
1       -1      1     -1
2       -1      6     -1
3       -1      1     -1
4       -1      6     -1
..     ...    ...    ...
995      2      4      3
996      2      0      0
997      8      5      7
998      3      5      5
999      5      7      7
```

**Performance**
In my local machine, using N=1000, the for loop is slightly faster. Increasing N to 1M, `apply` method is faster:

```py
def for_loop(N):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, (N,3)), 
                  columns=['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C'])
    for col, idx in s.iteritems():
        df.loc[:idx, col] = -1
    return df

def apply_method(N):

    def f(c, s):
        c[:s[c.name]] = -1
        return c

    return df.apply(lambda c: f(c,s))

%timeit for_loop(1000)
1.19 ms ± 58.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit apply_method(1000)
185 ms ± 44.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit for_loop(1000_000)
303 ms ± 25.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit apply_method(1000_000)
162 ms ± 8.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Loop s are not `fast and less consuming method.`

Comment: yes that's what I'm looking for, I've used a for loop (check my code in question, i've edited it) but the for loop is taking too much time when the columns get more

Comment: @jezrael Please suggest/post a vectorized implementation, I am looking forward to that :). Also, here we are only looping through a series with size `len(df.columns)`

Comment: @FBruzzesi - I am waiting for divakar ;)

Comment: Do you think that defining a custom function and using apply would speed this up?

Comment: my gut feeling is there is something with apply or map but I get some difficulties manipulating these functions

Comment: @jezrael added apply implementation

Comment: yes, it is better, although `apply` are loops under the hood.